# How to implement find as you type on a TComboBox descendant

Tags: delphi, user-interface, vcl, custom-component

What is the correct way to implement the "find as you type" behavior on a TComboBox descendant component whose style is csOwnerDrawFixed?

Comment: Depends, do you only want to implement the "search as you type" part, without displaying any feedback to the user (the way Firefox does it on long lists, for example), or do you want to show an small sub-control displaying the current search string?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a TTimer (let's call it timIncSearch). Set (at design time) the following properties:
   Enabled:=False;
   Interval:=400; //empirically found - it's the delay used in Windows Explorer

...and in OnTimer you'll wrote your searching engine. Be sure that the first line here will be timIncSearch.Enabled:=False; Also because you use csOwnerDrawFixed perhaps it's better to enforce a repaint of your control.

As an aside, - just guessing because you didn't give us many details - perhaps you must hook OnEnter and OnExit events to custom open and close the DropDown list. (Normaly, this is achieved by setting the AutoDropDown property accordingly)

2. In your ComboBox.KeyPress you'll write

`with timIncSearch do

    begin

      Enabled:=False;

      Enabled:=True;

    end;`

...also take care here, perhaps you must have a 'case Key of' construct to handle the #13 separately (or whatever).

Other hints:

- depending on your situation, perhaps you must hook (also?) the OnKeyDown (if you want to process special keys like eg. BackSpace, Del, Arrows etc. - *taking* in account that the event repeats itself while the key it's pressed down) and/or OnKeyUp (if you want to do similar processing as above but *without* taking in account the keyboard's key auto-repeat feature).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide whether you need "*my_string*" or "my_string*"  functionality, meaning deciding if you would search inside the strings or just from the beginning.
When you have figured that out, then you would have to buld the index of all the words entered in the combo box and search it after every keystroke.
I don't think that handling OnTimer is a right approach. I would rather use "OnChange" or similar. 
You could do it with sorted (dupignore) TStringList, or maybe build the index using hash tables (the implementation is up to you).
The architecture depends on the max no of strings your combo could contain. If it is a significant number than you could use hash tables (one hash Cardinal pointing to multiple indexes : array, TList...)